# How can I conditionally edit strings in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame containing for example the columns A, B and C.
Now I want for example edit all values of B (strings) by: if the string contains ":", delete everything after the ":".

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict = {
               'A' : ["stuff", "stuff"],
               'B' : ["stu:ff", "stuff"],
               'C' : ["stuff", "stuff"]
              }
test_frame = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try via `replace()`:

```
test_frame['B']=test_frame['B'].replace(r':.*','',regex=True)
```

OR

try via `str.replace()`:

```
test_frame['B']=test_frame['B'].str.replace(r':.*','',regex=True)
```

output:

```
       A      B      C
0  stuff    stu  stuff
1  stuff  stuff  stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your answer works perfectly for the example. But what I like to know ist how I can use more complex conditions. For example "if the first value is ',' delete this part of the string" or "if n'th string of 'B' is 'abc' append 'd' to it".

Comment: @Pm740 for that you need proper regex pattern